# integration by parts to solve this problem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please show me the steps to solve
$$
\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}dx
$$
with integration by parts. I did it twice and got all different answers. I know the answer has to be -1.712. Thanks for your help

Comment: It is unlikely that that is the answer. At most, that is an approximation to the answer. It is good practice not to approximate until you really need it.

Comment: http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP32871bf3d2g2ae3b6hg3000055gg5fdd26c185h8?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=35&w=573.&h=59.

that is the answer

Comment: @jainsmit I believe Franklin's comment was a suggestion that you not **approximate** $\sqrt 5(e -3)e$ unless asked to. Note that in your image, the $\approx$ symbol means exactly this: that it is *approximately* equal to an infinitely long decimal expansion, for which $-1.712$ is even "less" of an approximation. Why not use the *exact answer* $\;\sqrt 5(e - 3)e$?

Comment: All I am saying is to look carefully at the symbol $\approx$. It is more useful when it is a $=$.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}dx$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot e^{\frac32}\int_{-1}^1xe^{-\frac12x}dx$$

Putting  $x=2y,dx=2dy$

When $x=-1,y=\frac x2=-\frac12$ and when $x=1,y=\frac x2=\frac12$

$$\implies I=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}e^{\frac32}\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}2ye^{-y}2dy=2\sqrt5e^{\frac32}\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}ye^{-y}dy$$

Now, 
$$
\begin{align}
\int ye^{-y}dy &= y\left(\int e^{-y}dy\right)-
\int\left(\frac{dy}{dy}\cdot\int e^{-y}dy\right)dy\\
&=-ye^{-y}+\int e^{-y}dy\\
&=-ye^{-y}-e^{-y}
\end{align}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: why did you make x = 2y?

Comment: @jainsmit Presumably to get a pure exponential in the integrand.

Comment: @jainsmit, as the power of $e$ is $-\frac x2$. We can set $y=-\frac x2$ as well

Comment: @labbhattacharjee im still not following you

Comment: @jainsmit, have you noticed the power of $e$ in the integrand

Comment: yes i did see that

Comment: @jainsmit, $e^{-\frac12x+\frac32}=e^{\frac32}\cdot e^{-\frac x2},$ observe that the first multiple is constant, hence can be taken out of the integrand

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I got that part. I do not get what happened next

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9542/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-jain-smit)

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_{-1}^{1}xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}dx =-2xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}|_{x=-1}^{x=1}  +2\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}dx=-2e-2e^2-4 e^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}|_{x=-1}^{x=1}$$

$$=-6e +2e^2.$$

We use the fact that $\int_a^bf'g = fg|_{a}^b-\int fg'$ and the fact that $\left(-2 e^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}\right)'=e^{-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}}.$

Comment: @Amzoti Multiplication by a constant is simple enough. The main problem was with integration by parts. I don't see why I should bloat the demonstration.

Comment: you will with this poster as s/he is learning a lot of things and you must be explicit, but that was just a friendly comment, ignore if you feel not important. Regards